# How to configure PCF router for https?

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, pcf, pcfdev

The web app I try to push is enabled with a https URL. When I push the image in to pcf like below,I can see the logs as its running but cannot browse as it gives me a 502 Bad Gateway. My docker image can be deployed successfully in my local repo. 
 Registered endpoint  failed to handle the request even though the push is shown as successful and web app is shown as the status as running.

```
cf push -u process --docker-image ushanib/wso2is:is5.3.0 is5.3.0
```

I pushed the tomcat web app it is running with no issue on https://tomcat.local.pcfdev.io/.

How can I solve this issue? 
Can this be due to the https url or any other reasons? 
PCF version : pcfdev-v0.26.0+PCF1.10.0-linux.zip

Comment: `web app I try to push is enabled with a https URL` - Can you explain this?  You don't push apps with an http/https route.  You push with a route and your app will be accessible on http/https depending on how your platform operator has configured the domain.  Most will have both, but in some cases, the operator may disable plain HTTP.

Comment: You can just push the app archive (jar / war / zip) directly to PCF Dev. Q, any particular reason you are using a docker image?